# AndroidStudio can't start virtual device

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

OS - Ubuntu 14.04.1, I am runing AndroidStudio as root(sudo su), starting it with all default settings. It loads the window where should appear the avd, but it stay black, i waited around 20 minutes, it kept black.

AVD Settings:

[image: Device settings]

After click ok:

[image: After click ok]

SDK installed things:
All from Android 5.0(API 21), Android SDK Build-Tools 20-21.0.1, Android Platform Tools 21, Android SDK Tools 23.0.5, Google Play Services 20, Google Support Repository 7, Google Support  Library 21, Google Repository 12

How to fix this problem, where to get some sort of log or something that can help in solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

go to the platform tools folder inside your sdk and type the following command

adb kill-server

adb start-server

now your virtual device will start showing.

Comment: The problem was that the Android Studio was trying to reach directory that don't have acces now i started it like root and the problem is solved, but the avd is only black screen i edited the main post, please read it.